# how to set background image and gradient via javascript - without jquery using dom style attribute

Tags: javascript, css

Not sure what the syntax should be for setting the background image and gradient (so that I can darken the image)

I can set the background image but not sure how I can set the linear gradient

```
  holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat';
  holder.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
  holder.style.backgroundlinearGradient = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'  //this doesn't work
```

Also, can I combine more than one property in style.background to set all 3 size and gradient and image in one line?

Note that I cannot use jquery and want to do this by setting dom attributes if possible.

Comment: I would try this without javaScript first.  ie just html and css

Comment: why not use jquery css() to set all at once

Comment: can't install jquery installed in this environment and this has to be set using javascript as an asynchronous response to an event.

Comment: `linearGradient` is not a CSS property. It is a **value** of the `background` property. Perhaps you are looking for the `filter` property if you want to darken the image.

Comment: use jQuery and add/remove a class where u define your css-values.

Comment: @torazaburo your right but the only thing he cannot know and fit the value with a variable is background-image. I'm talking about linear-gardient and background-size. But another question is if he want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I'm just a js newbie, however, I believe you can combine all your background properties into one larger declaration, or add them through some vars that contain info regarding your css, such as:

```
var some_fancy_gradient = 'linear-gradient(red, blue)';
var some_fancy_image = 'your url'
yourelement.style.background = 'url('+some_fancy_image+') center center / cover no-repeat,'+some_fancy_gradient+' no-repeat';
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5tL4vqj2/)**

Don't know if this is what your looking for, but may point you in the right direction.

Also, some documentation:

- [css3 gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)
- [multiple backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/)
- [background property shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) & [even more bg stuff](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)

Comment: That js fiddle is pretty awesome, great santa BTW

Comment: BTW, what's the syntax for concatenating all those properties, do they have to be in a certain order, when to use slash or commas - is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Thanks, glad to help out! Ill post in a sec some resources

Comment: There, hope that helps out

Comment: Put all the styling in a css class and just add or remove the className property in javascript.Seems pretty clean.

Comment: oh cool, so to darken the image I'll need to declare the gradient first before the background image